# iOS : UI - Design login page and Tab view - Tab not coming after Login

Tags: ios, user-interface, view, tabs

I am a newbie in iOS development. I want to create 2 screens - (1) Login & on successful login (2) a Tab based view.

I started up with creating Login text boxes & button for Login in Storyboard. Now, how do I create other Tab view & show that new tab view on login btw click.

What would be the best approach for creating this type of screens ? In tutorials, I can find of creating Tabbed View as main or dynamic. Couldn't find the way I am looking for. FYI, I would like my app to be compatible with iOS 4 and above. I wish to plan and use resources accordingly. Sharing this, as in case it affects the approach to be selected.

Thanks

**UPDATED AGAIN :**
As shown/suggested in answer, I created a new project as TabbedView and added LoginViewController to the storyboard. In my LoginViewController under "Identity Inspector" - Identity - StoryboardID - gave name "loginViewController". Created Custom class for TabControl - MC_MainTabBarController. 
 My storyboard file name is Main_iPhone.storyboard.
In my AppDelagate file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method before return I added :

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
// MY First View of Tab
MC_ChatViewController *chatViewTab = [[MC_ChatViewController alloc] init];
// MY TabController class
MC_MainTabBarController *tabCtrler = [[MC_MainTabBarController alloc] init];
// Login view controller 
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
[loginViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[tabCtrler presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This should bring first Login screen and then the tabs, but it brings straight away tabs & no login screen. I feel I might be going wrong at 2 places -  "Main_iPhone" OR I may have to set loginViewController as storyboard id somewhere else also. Where can't get it ?

**UPDATE**

Even after calling tabCtrler presentViewContorller ... also, still Login screen isn't showing up. Yet straight tabs are only visible. At Runtime, I see the following Warning :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x8ab4e80> on <MC_MainTabBarController: 0x8d4dc20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

**UPDATE** 
With the below code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate I can get my login page.

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
MC_MainTabBarController *tabCtrler = [[MC_MainTabBarController alloc] init];
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:loginViewController];
```

Now, from Login -submitBtnClick, how do I get to my default Tab view ?? That should be handled in submitBtnClick in login class or her in AppDelegate only. How to achieve the same ?

Can please help to bring the login screen prior to tabs.

Thanks

Comment: Set `TabbarController` as root and present `LoginViewController` over it. And on successful login dismiss `LoginViewController`.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, Thanks. If you can you tell how to do this or refer any tutorial that shows how to achieve the same would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks BoranA & all friends,

I had to extend BoranA's answer for this to work, hence am sharing the solution that worked for me. AS BoranA instructed,

1. I created a new Project with tabbed template.
2. add LoginViewController screen to the Storyboard and gave it Id - "loginViewController".
3. Created class's for LoginViewController and MC_MainTabBarController for the main tab controller.
4. Added Storyboard Id to tab controller as "mainView".

In AppDelgate.h, added properties for loggedIn & tabController object

```
@property (nonatomic) bool isLoggedIn;
@property(nonatomic,strong)MC_MainTabBarController *tabBarController;
```

In AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Show Login view if not logged On
if (!self.isLoggedIn) {
    [self showLoginScreen:NO];
}

return YES;
}

-(void) showLoginScreen:(BOOL)animated {
    // Get login screen from storyboard and present it
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Show the Login Screen
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:animated completion:nil];    
}

-(void) logout {

    // Remove data from singleton (where all my app data is stored)
    //[AppData clearData];

    // Reset view controller (this will quickly clear all the views)
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    // Create the tabBarController using Storyboard ID 
    self.tabBarController = (MC_MainTabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];
    // Show the Tab Bar Controller
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

    // Show login screen
    [self showLoginScreen:NO];
}
```

Finally, in LoginViewController.m, when I am done with all process and have to show the main view, I call the following method :

```
-(void) loginWasSuccessful {
     // Send Notification
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginSuccessful" object:self];

     // Dismiss Loginscreen
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

// LOGIN BTN CLICKED
- (IBAction)loginBtnClicked:(id)sender {
     // Validate & Process Login

     // If user is logged successfully, then only go to the main view.
     if (self.processLogin)
        [self loginWasSuccessful];
}
```

With this code, if isLoggedIn if AppDelegate is true, then it will straight away show the Tab controller and won't show Login screen. IF isLoggedIn is false, then first Login screen will come up and on successful login only tab controller will show up.

Hope this helps someone save time and get solution to their problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a project with tabbed application template.
2. Create your LoginViewController separately in your storyboard.
3. Add below code to your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

   ```
   if (!isLoggedIn)
   {
       LoginViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
       [loginViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
       [yourTabbarController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
   }
   ```

note: Dont't forget to specify storyboard id of your view as "loginViewController".

Comment: Create your LoginViewController separately in your storyboard. - How do I add this to the main Tab storyboard ? Can I do anything with the existing project - the main storyboard is already the Login part. Maybe like, create a Tab storyboard & set that as main & add existing main (Login) to this new one. Can such a way be possible achieved easily ?

Comment: First question: Just drag&drop a View Controller to the storyboard and set custom class as LoginViewController. Second question: I think creating a new project is much more easier for your situation. Setting entry point and creating a tab bar from scratch can be hard.

Comment: Added ViewController to storyboard & components to the view. If I set custom name to newly added View Controller as "LoginViewController" then nothing comes up - I mean to add/bind events, properties, etc. Even on executing the app, I don't find LoginViewController .h & .m files in the project.

Comment: You should create it from File-New-File-UIViewController. Maybe you should read some document before starting.

Comment: Yes I had missed that part of it. The object storyboard you have used to initialize LoginViewController, where have you set its name. I mean set "storyboard" object name ?

Comment: Please check updated question and help with it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You aren't presenting the loginView. That's the missing part. [yourTabbarController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: I thought as FirstView & SecondView Controllers have their classes, TabbarController should have its own. But it wasn't so I added a class and set it as Custom Class to my TabBar Controller. And in AppDelegate, addedMC_MainTabBarController *tabCtrler = [[MC_MainTabBarController alloc] init][tabCtrler presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];  YET I don't see my login view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48581/discussion-between-tvd-and-borana)